# ML on dataset with heavy dependency on prefix

Tags: machine-learning

I have a target function, which heavily depends on vector prefix:

> (**1, 2**, 0, 0, 1, 2, 4) -> **A**
>
> (**1, 2**, 0, 55, 1, 99, 1) -> **A**
>
> (**1, 2**, 124, 55, 1, 99, 71) -> **A**
>
> (**1, 3**, -5, 0, 1, 2, 4) -> **B**
>
> (**1, 3**, 12, 55, 1, 99, 1) -> **B**
>
> (**1, 3, 124**, 55, 1, 99, 71) -> **C**
>
> (**1, 3, 124**, 21, 10, 195, 11) -> **C**
>
> ...

Prefix length may vary.

**pre-condition:** a training set of vectors and their target values

**target:** to be able to evaluate target value on arbitrary vector

I have tried HMM, but it doesn't seem to work well in this case. What algorithm should I use instead?

Answer (score 2):

Consider LSTMs. They're a type of recurrent neural network that are generally very good at sequence prediction tasks and have the ability to learn very long range dependencies like you describe.

[Andrej Karpathy gives a tremendously great intro to RNN/LSTM on his blog.](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/)

Although going as far as a neural network opens up a whole new range of problems, such as long training time and finding the right architecture and gradient descent parameters. If your problem is very dependent on only a handful of terms then you may be able to get adequate results with a tabular multinomial regression approach and some smart encoding of your sequence. Something like:

```
y prefix1 prefix2 prefix3 has1 has2 has3  ...
A       1       2       0    1    1    0  ...
B       1       3      -5    1    0    1  ...
```